# R: Efficient Way to partly modify diagonal of matrix

Tags: r, performance, rcpp, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

I have a square matrix with dimension ranging from 100x100 to 10,000x10,000.  The matrix represents parameter values for a function.  I go through a loop where I try various combinations of parameters.  Every iteration `W` has a different value so I have to update the locations in the matrix which have the value `W`.  This happens to be the even entries of the diagonal, so `[2,2]`, `[4,4]`, etc. I am curious if there is a more efficient way to do this than my current approach:

```
W<-treeDepth*newVar
for (iW in evenDiag) {
  matrixSource[iW,iW]<-W
}
```

So far I've only tested with 134x134 size matrices, but looping appears to be the fastest approach according to analysis with `profvis`.

When I try

```
diag(matrixSource)[evenDiag]<-W
```

It appears to take similar amounts of time, but it starts calling < GC> after an average of every 5 calls or so, but the actual times < GC> is called appear to be random.

I think < GC> is garbage collection, but whatever it is, it takes forever, and it's rarely if ever called when I have the loop version above.

Am I wrong to think there's a better approach than looping one by one.  Would writing the loop in `Rcpp` make it faster?  Hadley in "Advanced R" doesn't say that writing values into a matrix would be faster with Rcpp so it probably doesn't.  If it did, how would I change that one little line(s) to Rcpp without making a C++ function or anything complicated (I don't know any C++).

According to my research it isn't possible to just write something like

```
matrixSource[evenDiag,evenDiag]<-W
```

but that if it were, R would excel at vectorized processing.

What is the best approach for this?

If it's helpful, the context is that the matrix needs to be fed into

```
negLogLik<- -mvtnorm::dmvnorm(flattenedData,sigma=matrixSource,log=T,checkSymmetry = FALSE)
```

and internally to that function it's fed into chol() (which sometimes calls < GC> in parallel)

So if there's a way I can modify that function to work with only partial matrices that aren't fully
created so that maybe I only have to assign the value of W once, that'd also be good.

I also need a way to assign the diagonal directly above and below the main diagonal all the same value, Z. Is there a good way to do that?

Thank you <3

Comment: `matrixSource[cbind(iW,iW)]<-W` should do what you want, can't speak to efficiency offhand.

Comment: you could also try regular vector indexing, e.g. `matrixSource[(iW - 1)*nrow(matrixSource) + iW] <- W` (might be off-by-one), or changing to sparse matrix representation of appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not found memory problems with square matrices up to dimension 1000.
[@MichaelChirico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3576984/michaelchirico)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77814255/r-efficient-way-to-partly-modify-diagonal-of-matrix/77814597#comment137180871_77814255) seems to be the most efficient. It runs in time constant with the matrix dimension, unlike `diag<-`.
The two methods used below are

```
# create an index
i <- rep(c(FALSE, TRUE), ncol(A) %/% 2)
j <- which(i)

# can also be diag(A)[i]
diag(A)[j] <- W

# cannot be cbind(i, i)
A[cbind(j, j)] <- 0
```

`cbind` is clearly more efficient.

```r
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

testFun <- function(N) {
  out <- lapply(seq.int(N)[-1L], \(n) {
    A <- matrix(1:n^2, n, n)
    W <- rep(0L, ncol(A) %/% 2L)
    i <- rep(c(FALSE, TRUE), ncol(A) %/% 2)
    j <- which(i)
    mb <- microbenchmark(
      diag = {diag(A)[i] <- W},
      cbind = {A[cbind(j, j)] <- W}
    )
    mb$dim <- n
    mb
  })
  out <- do.call(rbind, out)
  aggregate(time ~ ., out, median)
}

testData <- testFun(1000)
ggplot(testData, aes(dim, time, colour = expr)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

Another way of assigning the diagonal elements of a square matrix is proposed by [user20650](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250190/user20650) in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77814255/r-efficient-way-to-partly-modify-diagonal-of-matrix/77814597?noredirect=1#comment137190838_77814597). Change the timimg instruction call above to

```
mb <- microbenchmark(
  diag = {diag(A)[i] <- W},
  cbind = {A[cbind(j, j)] <- W},
  sq = {A[j*j] <- W}
)
```

and the plot (without `diag`) becomes

[image]

Comment: wow. this is amazing. thanks!  I only run cbind once since the entries that take the value W are always the same.  But it does appear that running cbind once and then executing `matrixSource[evenDiagBinded]<-W` each iteration is a little faster than running `for (iW in evenDiag) {
            matrixSource[iW,iW]<-W
          }` each iteration after compilation (not sure about uncompiled).  Probably the `matrixSource[evenDiagBinded]<-W` syntax gives the most efficient code for changing the matrix values?

Comment: @AFriendlyFish If you run `cbind` to see its code you will see `.Internal(cbind(deparse.level, ...))`. `cbind` is written in optimized C and therefore I was expecting it to be efficient. Even difficult to improve upon. But the indexing has code to handle non-square matrices so it might be further optimized, I guess.

Comment: as updating the diagonal of a **square** matrix could use `sq = {A[j*j] <- W}` which I'd think would be faster (only tested on small matrices)

Comment: @user20650 You are right, I have tested it on matrices with dim = 2:1000 and it's faster.

Comment: Thanks @RuiBarradas. Interesting that something seems to happen around 600 dimension.